# Is there any alternative to GViz on Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

The problems:

1. I need to get data in a kind of "relational" way.
2. GViz (Google Visualization API) is not available for GAS (Google Apps Script) HTML Service (see here: [Can we use Google Chart Tools with Google Script HtmlService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231535/can-we-use-google-chart-tools-with-google-script-htmlservice?rq=1)).

Getting all the functinality GViz delivers is a dream right now, so, instead, I'd be satisfied with DataTable and DataView objects and google.visualization.data.join(). I dont need charts right now.

All of this, as long as I cannot get full GViz on the client side, could be server side.

Being more explicit, I need to join some queries and not mess up with the normalized data.

Keep in mind that I'm using a Spreadsheet as a data container (the tables are composed of static and dynamic data).

Answer (score 1):

Getting all the functionality from GViz is everyone's dream right now, but some of it is available through Charts Services in UiApps. I have no experience with HTML Service, so I can't speak for that.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_charts

If you're manipulating a lot of data, have you looked at ScriptDB?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_scriptdb

I currently use a set of spreadsheets and Charts Services for a dashboard and it works pretty well. I really wish I could make combo charts, though.

Comment: at the moment, ScriptDB is not an option (I have some running totals that are ordered dependent -- the spreadsheet saves a lot of computing time and a lot of coding).  About the Charts Service I'm not sure, cause I didn't find a 'google.visualization.data.join()' equivalent functionality.  +1 for the Charts Service (I need to get a grasp of it)

Comment: I don't know of an equivalent to data.join(). Assuming you have two sheets with data you're trying to combine, you can write a script to look for matches in the other values array, or you can use VLOOKUP functions in the spreadsheet to combine all the data together in one sheet, then read that.
I agree that spreadsheets can save a lot of time on computation. VLOOKUPs are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sometime between mid-March and now, GViz mostly works with HTML Service.

I'm very new to Google Apps Script myself, but I have managed to get TaffyDB working server side. I loaded it up as a library in case I want to use it across multiple projects.

I did have to add this line to make it work server side:

```
function setTimeout() {}
```

Not sure if the is necessarily sufficient, but it worked as a starting point.